# Python remove duplicates in list of list based on one part of sublist

Tags: python

I have a list in python like so

```
[
  [12,15],
  [13,16],
  [14,17],
  [14,18],
  [14,18],
  [15,19],
  [16,19],
  [17,19],
  [18,20],
]
```

How do I remove duplicates from that list based on ONLY the 2nd column of the sublist.  So that I get the following:

```
[
  [12,15],
  [13,16],
  [14,17],
  [14,18],

  [15,19],


  [18,20],
]
```

And what if I wanted to keep the LAST one insted of the first?  Like so:

```
[
  [12,15],
  [13,16],
  [14,17],

  [14,18],


  [17,19],
  [18,20],
]
```

So removing duplicates based on the sublist. And choosing to keep first or last.

Edit:

I forgot to mention I also need to keep the original list in order (minus the duplicates).  Ordering is important, and the list won't always be in counting order (12,13,14, etc, it will be random numbers instead).

Comment: vhere is your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an OrderedDict for this. Insert the items into the dictionary by the sorted value. Successive inserts will overwrite previous values. So, the order of insertion chooses whether to use the first or last duplicate value found. OrderedDict remembers the order that items were inserted.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [[12, 15], [13, 16], [14, 17], [14, 18], [14, 18],
     [15, 19], [16, 19], [17, 19], [18, 20]]

use_first_value = OrderedDict((i[1], i) for i in reversed(l))
filtered_list = list(reversed(use_first_value.values()))
print(filtered_list)

use_last_value = OrderedDict((i[1], i) for i in l)
filtered_list = list(use_last_value.values())
print(filtered_list)
```

Update: refactoring the code above into a common method that supports either direction and a key function. I'm not sure how Python does the default key function parameter to functions like `sorted()` so I've used a lambda that returns the item passed.

```
import operator

def remove_duplicates(items, key=lambda x: x, keep_older=False):
    # iter acts like an identity function here, i.e. no 
    # change to the order and Python would have called it
    # anyway.
    sort_fn = iter if keep_older else reversed
    values = OrderedDict((key(i), i) for i in sort_fn(items)).values()
    return list(sort_fn(values))

# Use a key function to make it more generic
key_fn = operator.itemgetter(1)

# prefer earlier items
remove_duplicates(l, key=key_fn)

# prefer later items
remove_duplicates(l, key=key_fn, keep_older=True)
```

Comment: This is perfect, and I have now learned about OrderedDict.  Thank you so much.  And it appears to work even when the duplicated items in the second element are NOT always adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set to keep track of duplicates, while copying elements into a new list:

```
seen = set([])
new_list = []
for item in l:
    if item[1] not in seen:
        new_list.append(item)
        seen.add(item[1])
```

To keep the last, just iterate over the list in reverse

```
for item in reversed(l):
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make this clear in the initial question (now updated) but will this preserve order? I thought set() would lose order. And I need to keep the ordering of the list (minus the duplicates).

Comment: are the second elements guaranteed to be in order from the start, i.e. all duplicates are next to each other?

Comment: @Nertskull The elements will be preserved in order. The set is only used to hold the values seen previously.

In the "keep last" example, the order will be reversed, but you can fix that by reversing it after the for loop: `new_list = reversed(new_list)`